# Serialize large, complex XML in C# or otherwise - goal is to import data into SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, xml, ssis

I have a very complex XML with an XSD that I'm trying to parse in C#.  I tried using XSD.EXE to build a class, but when I put this into C# I'm getting an error plus I'm unsure exactly how to serialize the XML into the class.  Below is an example of one of the smaller XML documents (data changed for example).

My goal is to get this data into SQL, but whether through C#, SSIS, or even TSQL I need some way to parse this data so I can push it into SQL.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Have you tried the [XMLSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization)?

Comment: “My goal is to get this data into SQL”. So why don't you just [store it as XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017c)? Why must you parse it first?

Comment: T-SQL can parse this directly into an `XML` variable, if you leave out the processing directive with the encoding. You can then use the `.query()` or `.nodes()` methods to shred the XML into relational tables. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type) for more. If you need no further complex processing of the XML, this is probably the most convenient approach, since it reduces the number of moving parts to 1.

Comment: You did not show the XML, but - if the format is appropriate - it might work to read this into a simple `DataSet`. Read about the various `ReadXml()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can automatically create c# objects from XML by creating new project in visual studio, copying your xml to clipboard and using

> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as classes